# Angular 6sass global variables

Tags: css, angular, sass

I defined a variable like this in the global scss called styles.scss in angular6

```
$color-redpink-dark: #E84A5F;
```

and I want to use the variable in a scss component, but when I declare the property  I have the next output:

```
  background-color: $color-redpink-dark;               
  Undefined variable: "$color-redpink-dark".
```

Should not the component scss use the color defined in the global scss?

Greetings.

Comment: can you check your angular.json file and see if your global styles.scss is there?

Comment: @IanP.yep, the global styles.scss is there :<

Comment: can you show your styles.scss file? I am assuming that it is in the correct folder structure as defined in your angular.json file (ie. when it says "src/global/styles.scss" in your angular.json, the `styles.scss` file should be physically inside the src/global folder) so I want to inspect how you are declaring the variables. If all is good, then you can use the @import command to load your global scss file into your component.

Answer (score 1):

You have to import the file with defined variable in the beginning of component.scss file using the variable:

```
@import 'your-file-name';

background-color: $color-redpink-dark;
```